Subtotaling a measure in an Excel pivot table
I know how I would handle this in SQL, but I'm being asked to do this in an Excel Power Query/Power Pivot, with which I am less familiar. I have medical data that looks something like this:



Doctor
Patient
Eligible for cervical screening
Received cervical screening
Eligible for colorectal screening
Received colorectal screening




Doctor1
Pat1
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes


Doctor1
Pat2
Yes
Yes
Yes
No


Doctor1
Pat3
Yes
No
Yes
Yes


Doctor1
Pat4
No
No
Yes
Yes


Doctor1
Pat5
No
No
Yes
No


Doctor1
Pat6
No
No
No
No



We also know that the goal for cervical screenings performed is at least 70%, and for colorectal screenings is at least 79%. This percentage is number performed over number eligible.
In Excel, we've been able to create a Pivot Table that looks like:



Doctor
Measure
Eligible
Performed
Goal
# Needed to Goal




Doctor 1
Cervical
3
2
70%
1


Doctor 1
Colorectal
5
3
79%
1


Doctor 1 Total

8
5

0



The formula for the # Needed to Goal measure is =ROUND(IF((MIN([Goal])/100 * [Sum of Eligible]) - [Sum of Received]<= 0, 0, (MIN([Goal])/100 * [Sum of Eligible]) - [Sum of Received]),0). The problem is that doctor total under #Needed to Goal in that lower right column. They want it to be 2, as in the sum of the #Needed to Goal from the cervical and colorectal lines. I can't figure out how to sum that measure in the subtotal row. I couldn't find an answer in Google, but I may not have been searching the right terms. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

In Power Query you can obtain your results table from your data with this code:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Doctor", type text}, {"Patient", type text}, {"Eligible for cervical screening", type text}, {"Received cervical screening", type text}, {"Eligible for colorectal screening", type text}, {"Received colorectal screening", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Doctor", "Patient"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Measure", each Text.Proper(List.LastN(Text.Split([Attribute]," "),2){0}), type text),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Doctor","Measure"}, {
        {"Eligible", (t)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(t, each Text.Contains([Attribute],"Eligible") and [Value]= "Yes")), Int64.Type},
        {"Performed", (t)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(t, each Text.Contains([Attribute],"Received") and [Value]= "Yes")), Int64.Type}}),

//Could have goals in a lookup table
// or enter them as Parameters
// and then alter the IF statement
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Goal", each 
        if [Measure] = "Cervical" then 0.7
        else if [Measure] = "Colorectal" then 0.79
        else null, 
        Percentage.Type),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "# Needed to Goal", 
        each Number.RoundAwayFromZero([Eligible] * [Goal] - [Performed]),Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Custom2"

You can then add the totals in the resultant table in Excel

Select the Table
Table Design => Totals Row

If you update the table, with the proper options, the totals row will also update.

You can also add a totals row within the query. That is more complex but doable. Let me know if you prefer that method.

Thank you! I may have over-oversimplified my data. In addition to the Doctor column, they also have tabs based on the same data that group by provider practice and patient employer. If I use your code, that would only do the total for doctors and I would have to do even mroe programming for the others, yes?

@KimLloyd If I understand you correctly, the only thing you might have to do is add those other grouping columns to the Keys argument of the Table.Group function. eg Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Doctor","Measure", "Practice","Employer"}, ... or similar.
